# Keep getting error when routing a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I keep getting this error when I try to route a button to a widget.

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/SantosDumont", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

This is the code. I want to call multiple historical figures using the info buttons class and then listing off each historical figure within ListTile like the Santos Dumont route

```
class Hwk3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hwk3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
class _Hwk3State extends State<Hwk3> {
  var nameArray = [
    'Pablo Picasso',
    'Santos Dumont'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Historical Figures'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(nameArray[index]),
              trailing: InfoButtons(historicalfigure: '/SantosDumont'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfoButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final String historicalfigure;

  InfoButtons({required this.historicalfigure});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        tooltip: "Press for more information on historical figure",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(historicalfigure);
        }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either define `/SantosDumont` in your routes inside `MaterialApp` or use `Navigator.of(context).push`.
Look at this link: [Navigate with named routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I defined /SantosDumont in my routes inside MaterialApp. Just wasn't able to post it because Stackoverflow didn't let me post the entire code.

Comment: Can you provide the error?